# Remove certain characters in a column Snowflake

Tags: sql, replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having data in a column like 'EARTH PLANET-ABC', 'MARS PLANET - ABC', 'JUPITER -ABC', 'VENUS- ABC' etc. I need to return the values 'EARTH PLANET', 'MARS', 'JUPITER', VENUS etc whenver the column has ABC at the end of the column. I tried `REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'ABC','')`. It removed the ABC from the entries in the column but it still returns the '-' and the space before/front of the ABC in the entry. I want to see EARTH PLANET', 'MARS', 'JUPITER', VENUS but I am getting 'EARTH PLANET-','MARS PLANET - ','JUPITER -','VENUS-' etc instead. Would a REGEXP help in this case?

Comment: Is there always a dash and spaces before ABC?

Comment: if you say REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'ABC','') it will only replace ABC.

if you say REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,' - ABC','') it will only replace space dash space ABC

is the space dash space a standard or does it change (as you've typed here)

Comment: the space and dash changes it is not standard but it is always at the end

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART(column,'-',1)::varchar
```

This splits your field by the hyphen and then gives you the first piece of it.  Seems like that's what you're looking for.  You might also need to trim the result to take care of any spaces that remain.

Answer (score 3):

some experimenting gives us these part answers, ENDSWITH look promising, but I used longer process in the end:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    ENDSWITH(trim(column1), 'ABC') as end_with_abc,
    SPLIT(column1, '-') as s,
    array_size(s) AS len_s,
    trim(get(s, len_s -1)) as last,
    charindex('-', REVERSE(column1), 3) as last_token,
    length(column1) - last_token as pos,
    substr(column1,1,pos) as prefix,
    iff(len_s > 1 AND last = 'ABC', prefix, column1) as answer
FROM values 
    ('EARTH PLANET-ABC'), 
    ('MARS PLANET - ABC'), 
    ('JUPITER -ABC'), 
    ('VENUS- ABC'),
    ('VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF'),
    ('VENUS - DEF');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | END_WITH_ABC | S | LEN_S | LAST | LAST_TOKEN | POS | PREFIX | ANSWER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EARTH PLANET-ABC | TRUE | [ "EARTH PLANET", "ABC" ] | 2 | ABC | 4 | 12 | EARTH PLANET | EARTH PLANET |
| MARS PLANET - ABC | TRUE | [ "MARS PLANET ", " ABC" ] | 2 | ABC | 5 | 12 | MARS PLANET | MARS PLANET |
| JUPITER -ABC | TRUE | [ "JUPITER ", "ABC" ] | 2 | ABC | 4 | 8 | JUPITER | JUPITER |
| VENUS- ABC | TRUE | [ "VENUS", " ABC" ] | 2 | ABC | 5 | 5 | VENUS | VENUS |
| VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF | FALSE | [ "VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF" ] | 1 | VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF | 0 | 17 | VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF | VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF |
| VENUS - DEF | FALSE | [ "VENUS ", " DEF" ] | 2 | DEF | 5 | 6 | VENUS | VENUS - DEF |

which can be compressed down to:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    SPLIT(column1, '-') as s,
    iff(array_size(s) > 1 AND trim(get(s, array_size(s) -1)) = 'ABC', substr(column1, 1, length(column1) - charindex('-', REVERSE(column1), 3)), column1) as answer
FROM values 
    ('EARTH PLANET-ABC'), 
    ('MARS PLANET - ABC'), 
    ('JUPITER -ABC'), 
    ('VENUS- ABC'),
    ('VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF'),
    ('VENUS - DEF');
```

or if you like super-compressed:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    iff(array_size(SPLIT(column1, '-')) > 1 AND trim(get(SPLIT(column1, '-'), array_size(SPLIT(column1, '-')) -1)) = 'ABC', substr(column1, 1, length(column1) - charindex('-', REVERSE(column1), 3)), column1) as answer
FROM values 
    ('EARTH PLANET-ABC'), 
    ('MARS PLANET - ABC'), 
    ('JUPITER -ABC'), 
    ('VENUS- ABC'),
    ('VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF'),
    ('VENUS - DEF');
```

| COLUMN1 | ANSWER |
| --- | --- |
| EARTH PLANET-ABC | EARTH PLANET |
| MARS PLANET - ABC | MARS PLANET |
| JUPITER -ABC | JUPITER |
| VENUS- ABC | VENUS |
| VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF | VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF |
| VENUS - DEF | VENUS - DEF |

OR

you can solve with REGEXP_SUBSTR:

```
SELECT
    column1 as orig,
    COALESCE(regexp_substr(column1, '^(.*)-\\s*ABC\\s*$', 1,1,'e'), column1) as answer
FROM values 
    ('EARTH PLANET-ABC'), 
    ('MARS PLANET - ABC'), 
    ('JUPITER -ABC'), 
    ('VENUS- ABC'),
    ('VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF'),
    ('VENUS - DEF');
```

giving:

| ORIG | ANSWER |
| --- | --- |
| EARTH PLANET-ABC | EARTH PLANET |
| MARS PLANET - ABC | MARS PLANET |
| JUPITER -ABC | JUPITER |
| VENUS- ABC | VENUS |
| VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF | VENUS_BUT_NOT_DEF |
| VENUS - DEF | VENUS - DEF |

Comment: The regexp_substr worked! Thanks! I still see a couple of entries like 'Earth 1 - text.serve ABC' and  'Earth 1 to 04_30_07-ABC' . Can you help with that?